# Post запрос регистрация

Tags: android, json, post

Доброго времени суток программисты, совсем недавно начал учить разработку моб.приложений под андроид, и столкнулся с такой проблемой нужно реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию в своем приложении при помощи Post запросов. Как я понял регистрация(Логин) выполняется с помощью post запроса на соответствующие ендпоинты, в теле запроса следует передавать json, например:

{
  "username": "user1",
  "password": "1234"
}

После регистрации(логина) возвращается токен или сообщение об ошибке.

Так как у меня опыта мало не знаю как реализовать что бы текстовые поля ввода логина пароля конвертировались в json формат, и отправлялись post запросом на соответствующие api/register(login).

Может у кого есть пример реализации подобной задачи или интернет источник где можно подучить материал для реализации данной задачи.

Сделал форму для ввода логина и пароля.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText emailText;
private EditText passwordText;
private Button   loginBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);
    initComponent();

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ((!emailText.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!passwordText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
            } else if ((!emailText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Password field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((!emailText.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Login name field empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Login name and Password field are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }            }
    });
}

private void initComponent() {
    emailText    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    loginBtn     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
 }
}
```

Написал при помощи вашего примера POST запроса регистрацию, но аккаунта оно по адресу http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/register/ не создает.

```
   public class PostReg {
  private static final String TAG ="mee";

  public static String doPost(String url, String jsonString) throws Exception {
    final String login = "yxz";
    final String password ="test";

        //jsonString = object.toString();

    URL obj = new URL("http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/register/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    //add reuqest header
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("usernam", login);
    jsonParam.put("password", password);

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .appendQueryParameter("username", login)
            .appendQueryParameter("password", password);
    String urlParameters  = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream dStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dStream, "utf-8"));

    //Send  request
    //DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    //outputStream.writeBytes(jsonString);
    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    Log.d(TAG,"\n-----------Send http request-----------");
    Log.d(TAG, "\nSending  request to URL : " + url);
    Log.d(TAG, "Post parameters : " + jsonString);
    Log.d(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

 //      print result
    Log.d(TAG,"Response string: " + response.toString());
    Log.d(TAG,"-----------end http request-----------\n");
    Log.d(TAG, "  ");

       return response.toString();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам, ниже рабочий код реализации регистрации:

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context c;
EditText regLogin;
EditText passwordText;
Button regloginBtn;
String password;
String rLogin;
String url = "http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/register/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    c = this;
    regLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_login_register);
    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password_register);
    regloginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    regloginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  _("Login button hit");

            rLogin = regLogin.getText() + "";
            password = passwordText.getText() + "";

            if ( rLogin.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if ( rLogin.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                //Do networking
                Networking n = new Networking();
                n.execute(url, Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER);
                Toast.makeText(c, "Register Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}


//AsyncTask good for long running tasks
public class Networking extends AsyncTask {

    public static final int NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        getJson((String) params[0], (Integer) params[1]);
        return null;
    }
}

private void getJson(String url, int state) {
    //Do a HTTP POST, more secure than GET
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    boolean valid = false;

    switch (state) {
        case Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER:
            //Building key value pairs to be accessed on web
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", rLogin));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            valid = true;


            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unknown state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if (valid == true) {
        //Reads everything that comes from server
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            //Send off to server
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //Reads response and gets content
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            //Read back server output
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        decodeResultIntoJson(stringBuffer.toString());
    } else {
    }
}

private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {
    if (response.contains("error")) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            String error = jo.getString("error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

        String success = jo.getString("success");
        String message = jo.getString("message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример POST запроса:

```
public static String doPost(String url, String jsonString)
            throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        //Send  request
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(jsonString);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        Log.d(TAG,"\n-----------Send http request-----------");
        Log.d(TAG, "\nSending  request to URL : " + url);
        Log.d(TAG, "Post parameters : " + jsonString);
        Log.d(TAG, "Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

//      print result
        Log.d(TAG,"Response string: " + response.toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"-----------end http request-----------\n");
        Log.d(TAG, "  ");

        return response.toString();
    }
```

Json строку можно сделать так:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("login", yourLogin);
object.put("password", yourPassword);
String jsonString  = object.toString();
```